# Passing Parameter to SSRSfrom asp.net

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I need to pass a parameter to reporting services which is on the reporting services server on my computer from my asp.net. The parameter is `SellerID`

```vb
MyReportViewer.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://jean-daniel/ReportServer_SQLEXPRESSADDD")
' Report Server URL
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report Project2/Auction History"
' Report Name
MyReportViewer.ShowParameterPrompts = False
MyReportViewer.ShowToolBar = False
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh()
Dim params(0) As ReportParameter
params(0) = New ReportParameter("SellerID", "201", False)
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(params)
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh()
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To pass parameters to a report via code you have to do it like this:

**C#**:

```cs
ReportParameter[] params = new ReportParameter[1]; 
params[0] = new ReportParameter("SellerId", ParameterValue , false); 
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(params); 
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

**VB.NET**:

```vb
Dim params(0) As ReportParameter
params(0) = New ReportParameter("SellerId", "YourValue", false)
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(params); 
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Here you can find a complete example [Generate SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) Report as PDF from URL with VB.NET or C#.NET](http://www.jensbits.com/2012/01/23/generate-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-report-as-pdf-from-url-with-vb-net-or-c-net/)

Comment: the parameter value is the value that i want to pass into the report/

Comment: do u have this in vb.net please

Comment: Exactly! And "sellerId" has to be the same as on the report

Comment: i'm having this problem @Raphael  The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable.Line 18:         MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(params)

Comment: it has edit the code above with your code can you see if i made any mistake please

Comment: You can delete the first refresh() method. Does reports with no parameter work? It seems to me that you have a connection problem with your server.

Comment: when i run it in the server it is ok? i run other report on the page it appear but for this one it does not appear i don't why when i run it without paramters